# Value reaches infinity too fast, how do I stop that from happening? (how do I make the program store higher numbers?)

Tags: swift, floating-point, infinity

This is my code so far:

```
let x = tgamma(a+b)
let y = tgamma(a)
let z = tgamma(b)

let norm = x / (y*z)
```

The type of 'x' is float. The problem in my code is that x reaches infinity too quickly. I am wondering whether there is a way to make the program store higher values for 'x'. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said

> The type of 'x' is float.

Swift doesn't have a type “float”. It has a type `Float`; in Swift, the capital letter is significant. I assume you meant that `x` has type `Float`.

The range of `Float` is about -3.4×10³⁸ to +3.4×10³⁸. If you need more range, you can try using `Double`, which has a range of about ±1.8×10³⁰⁸.

To use `Double`, convert your inputs to `Double` before calling `tgamma`. Example:

```
let x = tgamma(Double(a) + Double(b))
let y = tgamma(Double(a))
let z = tgamma(Double(b))

let norm = x / (y*z)
```

However, since `tgamma` (aka Γ, the gamma function) grows quickly, you might want to use `lgamma` instead. `lgamma` returns the absolute value of the natural logarithm of Γ, so it returns finite answers for a much larger range of inputs. If your inputs are positive, this should work:

```
// log(x / (y * z)) = log x - (log y + log z)

let lx: Double = lgamma(Double(a) + Double(b))
let ly: Double = lgamma(Double(a))
let lz: Double = lgamma(Double(b))

let lnorm = lx - (ly + lz)
let norm = exp(lnorm)
```

Comment: Yes, that is obviously what I meant. Thanks a lot for answering, it was truly helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the logarithmic gamma function instead and replace multiplication and division with addition and subtraction of the calculated values

```
let x = lgamma(a+b)
let y = lgamma(a)
let z = lgamma(b)

let norm = x.0 - (y.0 + z.0)
```